# JavaScript Constructor usage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using the below line of code for one of the requirement -

```
class App {
  constructor(){
    this.obj = { val1: null, val2: '' };
  }
```

}

And changed the above code to something below:

```
class App {
  obj = { val1: null, val2: '' };
}
```

I could not see any difference between the above two code for the functionality aspects and both code snippets work the same way. I tried the same in the `babeljs` playground with preset `"stage-3"` and they are producing the same results.

Can you please let me know if any other differences between the above code and issues using one over the other?

Comment: The first bit of code is questionable code: did you mean `this.obj = ... `? Because without `this.` you're declaring "a variable `obj` in whatever is the current scope", in a way that isn't even allowed under strict rules.

Comment: The first example throws `ReferenceError: obj is not defined` when you try to construct an object.

Comment: I think you meant `this.` ?

Comment: one different is : The constructor() method can be called automatically by new

Comment: Yes you are right I edited the constructor to reference this as mentioned by CertainPerformance in the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same. In the first code, you're assigning to a *standalone variable* named `obj`. (Hopefully you defined it beforehand, eg `let obj;`, otherwise an error will be thrown; constructors always run in strict mode)

```js
let obj;
class App {
  constructor(){
    obj = { val1: null, val2: '' };
  }  
}
const app = new App();
console.log(obj);
console.log(app.obj);
```

```js
class App {
  constructor(){
    obj = { val1: null, val2: '' };
  }  
}
const app = new App();
console.log(app.obj);
```

```js
class App {
  obj = { val1: null, val2: '' };
}
const app = new App();
console.log(app.obj);
```

In the second code, you're assigning an `obj` property to the instance at the beginning of the constructor. The second code is equivalent to:

```
class App {
  constructor(){
    this.obj = { val1: null, val2: '' };
  }  
}
```

Browser compatibility is also a concern. Class field syntax (which is what your second code is using) is very new; if you want to use it and have anything other than *very recent* browsers be able to understand the code, make sure to use Babel before serving it to clients.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lack of `this.` to be a typo, which I'm inclined to believe it is in order to take this question seriously, there aren't any functional differences but code comprehension is easier with the latter. As the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) points out,

> By declaring fields up-front, class definitions become more self-documenting, and the fields are always present.

Programmers can see at a glance what the class variables are without having to refer into and read through the constructor. It also gives a "default" value to the field.

It also prevents errors that could happen due to misodering of initialization within the constructor. It's a best practice to use "Public field declarations".

```
class A {

  constructor() {
    this.obj.foo <--- // error
    this.obj = { foo: 1 }
  }
}

class A {
  obj = { foo: 1 } // <-- self-documenting

  constructor() {
    this.obj.foo   // <-- no error
  }
}
```